# how to receive data from client on server in nodejs over http

Tags: node.js

These are my two files and I'm not able to print "hi i m client" from client,js, however the message from the server.js can be printed easily on my client terminal

```
// client.js
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('client_key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('client_cert.pem'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000,
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    agent: false 
};
var request = https.request(options, function(response) {
    console.log('response.statusCode:', response.statusCode);
    request.write("hi i m client");
    //response.write('Hi i m res client');
    //response.pipe(my);
    response.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('got some data back from the server:' + data);
    });
});
request.end();
```

this is my server.js:

```
// my server.js
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var options = {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 3000,
    key: fs.readFileSync('server_key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server_cert.pem'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};
var server = https.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
    //console.log('inside the server::',req.socket);
    req.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('recieved::' + data);
    });
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.write("hi i mm server");
    res.end();
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Here are a couple of suggestion that will help SO users to answer your question: 1. Including your code is important so good job, but code formatting is important, have a look at [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to make your code more readable. 
2. You've told us what you want to the code to do which is great but it's always a good idea to specifically say what `Error` you are getting so we can identify the potential problem in your code more easily.